# PanGestureHandler with functional component react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-gesture-handler

I am trying to use a Gesture handler with a functional component. The problem is when I drag for the second time it's dragging from initial position again

[image]

This is my code below

```
let translateXRef = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

const onGestureEvent = useCallback(
    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            translationX: translateXRef,
          },
        },
      ],
      { useNativeDriver: true }
    ),
    []
  );

<View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF80',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      height: 100,
    }}
  >
    <PanGestureHandler
      onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
      onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}
    >
      <Animated.View
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: 10,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.buttonColor,
          transform: [{ translateX: translateXRef }],
        }}
      />
    </PanGestureHandler>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `context` in addition to the `event` in your callback.

I'm not sure why you're using the `Animated.event`. You should generate your callbacks using the `useAnimatedGestureHandler`.

Each of those callbacks `onStart`, `onActive`, `onEnd`, etc... take an `event` and `context` argument.

The `context` argument is an object that would let you set your previous position so that then next click would not reset the position.

Here's more info:

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/events/#using-context

Also, a pretty good video that explains it:

https://youtu.be/4HUreYYoE6U